# Lazy split and semi-lazy split

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, lazy

Sometimes I need to be able to split data into chunks, and so something like [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) would be helpful. This comes with two downsides:

1. Input has to be strings
2. You consume all input when generating the output.

I have a couple of requirements:

- It needs to work with any iterable / iterator. Where the items have the `!=` comparator.
- I don't want to consume the chunk of data when returning it.
  Rather than returning a tuple, I need to return a generator.

And so this left me with two ways to implement the code. A fully lazy version `isplit`. And one that is semi-lazy where it consumes some of the generator, when moving to the next chunk, without fully consuming it.

And so I created:

```
from __future__ import generator_stop
import itertools


def _takewhile(predicate, iterator, has_data):
    """
    Return successive entries from an iterable as long as the 
    predicate evaluates to true for each entry.

    has_data outputs if the iterator has been consumed in the process.
    """
    for item in iterator:
        if predicate(item):
            yield item
        else:
            break
    else:
        has_data[0] = False


def isplit(iterator, value):
    """Return a lazy generator of items in an iterator, seperating by value."""
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    has_data = [True]
    while has_data[0]:
        yield _takewhile(value.__ne__, iterator, has_data)


def split(iterator, value):
    """Return a semi-lazy generator of items in an iterator, seperating by value."""
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    has_data = [True]
    while True:
        carry = []
        d = _takewhile(value.__ne__, iterator, has_data)
        try:
            first = next(d)
        except StopIteration:
            if not has_data[0]:
                break
            yield iter([])
        else:
            yield itertools.chain([first], d, carry)
            carry.extend(d)
```

An example of these working are below. There is an edge case with `isplit`, which is as far as I know inherent from the code being fully lazy. This is shown below too.

```
print('isplit')
print([list(i) for i in isplit('abc def ghi', ' ')])
print([list(i) for i in isplit(' abc def ghi', ' ')])
s = isplit('abc def ghi', ' ')
print(list(itertools.zip_longest(*itertools.islice(s, 4))))

print('\nsplit')
print([list(i) for i in split('abc def ghi', ' ')])
print([list(i) for i in split(' abc def ghi', ' ')])
s = split('abc def ghi', ' ')
print(list(itertools.zip_longest(*itertools.islice(s, 4))))
```

Which outputs:

```
isplit
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
[('a', 'b', 'c', None), ('d', 'e', 'f', None), (None, 'g', 'h', None), (None, 'i', None, None)]

split
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
```

Comment: Is `has_data` necessary? Furthermore, why is it a list of booleans instead of just a boolean? If you get rid of `has_data` you can use `itertools.takewhile` also...

Comment: @Dair If you remove `has_data`, or change it to just a boolean, then the code will return an infinite amount of empty generators...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I would prefer the name `iterable` for the iterable argument (compare the documentation for the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module), and `sep` for the seperator argument (compare the documentation for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)).
2. `isplit` has the unsatisfactory feature that you cannot ignore any of the returned iterators — you have to consume each one fully before moving on to the next, otherwise the iteration goes wrong.

   For example, suppose we want to select words starting with a capital letter. We might try:

   ```
   for word in isplit('Abc def Ghi', ' '):
       first = next(word)
       if first == first.upper():
           print(first + ''.join(word))
   ```

   But this produces the output:

   ```
   Abc
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
   StopIteration
   ```

   Instead, we have to ensure that we consume each `word` iterator fully, even if we don't care about it:

   ```
   for word in isplit('Abc def Ghi', ' '):
       first = next(word)
       if first == first.upper():
           print(first + ''.join(word))
       else:
           for _ in word:
               pass
   ```

   The same issue arises with the standard library function [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), where calling code might move on to the next group before it has finished iterating over the previous group. `groupby` solves this problem for us by fully consuming the previous group as soon as the caller moves on to the next group. It would be helpful for `isplit` to do the same.
3. The similarity with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) suggests that we could implement `isplit` very simply in terms of `groupby`, like this:

   ```
   from itertools import groupby

   def isplit(iterable, sep):
       """Generate the contiguous groups of items from the iterable that are
       not equal to sep.

       The returned groups are themselves iterators that share the
       underlying iterable with isplit(). Because the source is shared,
       when the isplit() object is advanced, the previous group is no
       longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be
       stored as a list.

       """
       for key, group in groupby(iterable, sep.__ne__):
           if key:
               yield group
   ```

   Note that this code behaves like plain `str.split()` in that it coalesces adjacent separators. If you need the behaviour to be more like `str.split(' ')`, with empty groups when there are adjacent separators, then it should be straightforward to add an `else:` clause to generate the necessary empty iterators, like this:

   ```
   for key, group in groupby(chain((sep,), iterable, (sep,)), sep.__ne__):
       if key:
           yield group
       else:
           for _ in islice(group, 1, None):
               yield iter(())
   ```

   This uses [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

   (There are a couple of minor optimizations you could make here: the 1-element tuple `(sep,)` could be stored in a variable and used twice, and `iter(())` could be a global constant since you don't need a new empty iterator each time.)

Comment: Holy ****, I didn't think to use `groupby` here... :O Your `split` isn't lazy like mine, and consumes the entire group before any of it is ever used. To achieve the same lazyness, your `split` should be your `isplit`. I think changing most `isplit`s to `split` should be enough to fix this.

Comment: I removed the comment about `split`.

Comment: Unfortunately `isplit`, as you said, [needs more code](https://gist.github.com/Peilonrayz/e897757c722ef3682bdc51777a403dfe) to work in the same way. I'm now unsure which way is simpler.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: It doesn't need to be as complicated as that; see the revised answer.

Comment: That's clever. But, you'd still need `carry` to make it work with `zip`.

Comment: Sure, but I don't believe that the `zip` use case is worth it — you have to read the whole iterable into memory (except possibly for the remainder of the last group) before you can zip any of it, so the laziness doesn't help much: you might as well use `map(list, ...)` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I can't really thing of any reason why that wouldn't be better.

Comment: My first thought was also to use `itertools.groupby()`, but I found that it, like `isplit()`, has some surprising behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with your code.

```
>>> print([list(i) for i in split(' abc def ghi ', ' ')])
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

This should however end in an empty list.

To fix this you only need to change the `while True` loop to `while has_data[0]`. Following this, you can merge the `except` and `else` together, meaning that you don't need the `try` at all. And so you can use:

```
def split(iterator, value):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    has_data = [True]
    while has_data[0]:
        carry = []
        d = _takewhile(value.__ne__, iterator, has_data)
        yield itertools.chain(d, carry)
        carry.extend(d)
```